# How to call a variable from one module from another module in VB Excel

Tags: excel, vba

First Module1:

```
Public Sub ConnectTERDATA()
Dim fso As Object, _
Fileout As Object, _
Sql As Object, _
objNet As Object, _
FS As Object

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cm = New ADODB.Command
Set Rec_set = New ADODB.Recordset
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim ip As String, _
db As String, _
Row As Integer, _
SharepointAddress As String, _
LocalAddress As String, _
UserID As String, _
Pass As String, _
CommandTimeout As Integer, _
ws As Worksheet, _
DS As String

Row = 1
UserID = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter your User ID")
Pass = InputBoxDK(Prompt:="Enter your Password")
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0 'To wait till the query finishes without generating error
cn.CommandTimeout = 5000
cn.Open "Data Source=TERA; Database=TERA; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=" & UserID & "; Password=" & Pass & "; Session Mode=ANSI;"
'Check for errors...
If cn.State = adStateOpen Then 'If connection is success, continue

MsgBox "Connected to TERADATA"
    End If
End Sub
```

Second Module2:

```
Public Sub DisconnectTERDATA()

    Call Module1.cn
    cn.Close


    MsgBox "Disconnected from TERADATA"
    End If
End Sub
```

But when i calling that variable "Cn" from module1 throwing below error as "Expected Procedure Not Varaibale" Can anyone help me here?

[image]

Comment: You can't "call a variable", only procedures. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to Separate one module(Connect Button) to Connect Teradata and another module(Disconnect Button) to disconnect

Comment: I think what you need is a Class module. It allows you to define an object (say, "Teradata"), and create its methods, such as: Teradata.Connect, Teradata.Disconnect.

Comment: Thanks,How to pass the userid and password values to class module?

Comment: create Property Let statements for each item you want to pass and then  assign values to those properties of your instance.

Comment: i will get User ID and password at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable in public Ex:

```
Public Userid as String
Public pass as String
```

Then we can use it in other normal modules